# I NEED TO CREATE A DICE OBJECT, automatically roll the dice the first time when the page is first loaded in my html js

Tags: javascript, html

hey guys i need some guidance on how to add onload to my dice roller

```
< script > 
      function rollDice() {
        var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
        var die2 = document.getElementById("die2");
        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
        die1.innerHTML = d1;
        die2.innerHTML = d2;
        status.innerHTML = "You rolled " + diceTotal + ".";}

</script>
```

Comment: <body onload='rollDice()'></body>

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct but the problem is you have not called this function anywhere. Also since you are dealing with DOM elements do you need to wait for the DOM to be loaded and ready before you call this function.

```
window.onload = rollDice();
```

If you are using jquery then it is better to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    rollDice();
})
```

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt, I have also provided the JS solution

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to the windows load event.

`window.load = rollDice();`